Combination of decoder and encoder for VAE interpolation
To get VAE interpolation I need decoder and encoder to be combined. Can you make a suggestion?
encoder = 
      NetGraph[{LinearLayer[64], Ramp, LinearLayer[32], 
        Ramp, {LinearLayer[2], LinearLayer[2]}}, {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}];

decoder = 
  NetGraph[{LinearLayer[32], Ramp, LinearLayer[64], Ramp, 
    LinearLayer[2]}, {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}];

vae = NetGraph[{encoder, decoder}, {1 -> {NetPort[2, "input"]} -> 2}]


In your example, you have the structure of a regular autoencoder; for linear structures like this, you can use NetChain instead of NetGraph (so you don't have to manually type the connections of each node).

Thank you for your guidance
